# What is the best way to write common templated functions where T could be std::array (fixed-size) or std::vector/list/deque (dynamically allocated)

Tags: c++, c++14

I would like to write a templated function which does some vector-maths on containers of (mathematical) vectors. I would like flexibility in the template argument, T, so that it could be `std::array` or `std::vector` or `std::list`. These types have very similar interfaces, with the main difference being that `std::array` is a fixed-size type, whereas `std::list` and `std::vector` may be dynamically resized (albeit with different memory models).

For the sake of this example, let's assume that the outer container is always `std::vector` and that the function returns a newly created vector of Ts:

```c++
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<typename T>
std::vector<T>
process_vectors (const std::vector<T>& vecs) {
    // Create the return object with the same numbers of T objects it is as vecs:
    std::vector<T> rtn (vecs.size());

    // The missing code, if T is std::vector, is to resize each member of rtn to
    // have the same size as each element of vecs. What's the best way to introduce
    // this small difference between the implementations?

    // Use iterators to work through vecs and rtn, as these are a common interface to
    // all the STL containers
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator vi = vecs.begin();
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator ri = rtn.begin();

    // For this example, let's just copy the input to the output, copying each T
    // element by element:
    while (vi != vecs.end()) {

        // For each mathematical vector in vecs, loop through its vector components:
        typename T::const_iterator vi_i = vi->begin();
        // And copy the result into the return's components:
        typename T::iterator ri_i = ri->begin();

        while (vi_i != vi->end()) {
            // The 'operation' of this function; performing a copy 
            // (My real code would do something more useful, like
            // auto-scaling the lengths of the vectors)
            *ri_i = *vi_i;
            // On to the next elements:
            ++vi_i;
            ++ri_i;
        }
        ++vi;
        ++ri;
    }

    return rtn;
}

int main() {
    // vector<array> version
    std::vector<std::array<float, 3>> the_vecs(3);
    the_vecs[0] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    the_vecs[1] = { 2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f };
    the_vecs[2] = { 3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f };
    std::vector<std::array<float, 3>> rtn_obj = process_vectors (the_vecs);
    cout << "vector<array> rtn_obj size is " << rtn_obj.size() << endl;

    // vector<vector> version will crash
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> the_vecs2;
    the_vecs2.push_back ({ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f });
    the_vecs2.push_back ({ 2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f });
    the_vecs2.push_back ({ 3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f });
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> rtn_obj2 = process_vectors (the_vecs2);
    cout << "vector<vector> rtn_obj2 size is " << rtn_obj2.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you compile and run this example, the first stanza in `main()` will work ok, and the second (the `vector<vector>` one) will crash with a memory error, because the elements of `rtn` are not allocated. So as far as I can see, I need to create two versions of this function, one with resizes for `vector<list>` or `vector<vector>` typed arguments, and one without any resizes for arguments typed like `vector<array<float, 3>>`.

Now, I know how to test at compile time for a different kind of `T`, so that I can write two separate implementations of this function, depending on whether `T` is `array` or `vector`. I'm using this code:

```c++
#include <array>
#include <list>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

// specialize a type for resizable stl containers
namespace is_resizable_vector_impl {
    template <typename T>       struct is_resizable_vector:std::false_type{};
    template <typename... Args> struct is_resizable_vector<std::vector <Args...>>:std::true_type{};
    template <typename... Args> struct is_resizable_vector<std::list   <Args...>>:std::true_type{};
    // etc, other types omitted
}
// I've omitted a similar test for fixed-size stl containers (i.e. std::array)

// From the typename T, set a value attribute which says whether T is a scalar (like
// float, double), a resizable list-like type (std::vector, std::list etc) or
// a fixed-size list-like type, such as std::array.
template <typename T>
struct number_type {
    static constexpr bool const scalar = std::is_scalar<std::decay_t<T>>::value;
    static constexpr bool const resizable = is_resizable_vector_impl::is_resizable_vector<std::decay_t<T>>::value;
    // 0 default                                    value 0 for default impl (vector-common)
    // 1 scalar == false and resizable == true   => value 1 for resizable vector implementations
    // 2 scalar == false and resizable == false  => value 2 for fixed-size vector implementations
    // 3 scalar == true                          => value 3 for scalar
    static constexpr int const value = scalar ? 3 : (resizable ? 1 : 2);
};

// Common/default implementation
template <int vtype = 0>
struct Implementation
{
    template<typename T>
    static std::vector<T> process_vectors (const std::vector<T>& vecs) {
        std::vector<T> rtn (vecs.size());
        // common/default implementation if possible...
        return rtn;
    }
};

// Resizable (T is std::vector or std::list) implementation
template <>
struct Implementation<1>
{
    template<typename T>
    static std::vector<T> process_vectors (const std::vector<T>& vecs) {
        std::vector<T> rtn (vecs.size());
        cout << "resizable T implementation with .resize()s" << endl;
        return rtn;
    }
};

// Fixed-size (T is std::array) implementation
template <>
struct Implementation<2>
{
    template<typename T>
    static std::vector<T> process_vectors (const std::vector<T>& vecs) {
        std::vector<T> rtn (vecs.size());
        cout << "fixed-size T implementation WITHOUT .resize()s" << endl;
        return rtn;
    }
};

// Scalar implementation omitted; it's outside the scope of this stackoverflow question

// Now I can write out
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> process_vectors (const std::vector<T>& vecs) {
    return Implementation<number_type<T>::value>::process_vectors (vecs);
}

int main ()
{
    // vector<array> version
    std::vector<std::array<float, 3>> the_vecs(3);
    the_vecs[0] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    the_vecs[1] = { 2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f };
    the_vecs[2] = { 3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f };
    std::vector<std::array<float, 3>> rtn_obj = process_vectors (the_vecs);

    // vector<vector> version
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> the_vecs2;
    the_vecs2.push_back ({ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f });
    the_vecs2.push_back ({ 2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f });
    the_vecs2.push_back ({ 3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f });
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> rtn_obj2 = process_vectors (the_vecs2);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I still have to duplicate quite a bit of code (with a copy of the function in `struct Implementation<1>` and another in `struct Implementation<2>`), even though the only difference here is the need to resize each element of `rtn`. So the question is "how would you avoid duplication of the function process_vectors?"

Thanks for reading!

Comment: `process_vectors` doesn't do anything useful what simple assignment can't do.

Comment: Why not just do `auto rtn (vecs);`?

Comment: This is what the entire iterator concept was made for.

Comment: In answer to @MarekR : My real code does vectory stuff like finding centroids, or auto-rescaling the lengths of the vectors. The copy operation is just a trivial example so as not to get in the way of the question about how to avoid code duplication between the versions.

Comment: @NathanOliver: See reply above

Comment: @NicolBolas: Right, so as you see all the iterator code in the example would be common, whether T is std::array or std::vector. How would you rewrite the first code block to allocate the vector<vector> elements without doing anything for T=vector<array>?

Comment: @SebastianJames `auto rtn(vecs);` will do exactly that.  If it's a vector of vectors, you get a properly sized one, and it it is a vector of arrays you'll also get a properly sized one, it'll just not be zero initialized.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Ok, I get you! I will try this out.

Comment: Out: std::vector<T> rtn (vecs.size());   In: std::vector<T> rtn(vecs); So, thanks @NathanOliver that's the solution. I will post the solution code and mark it as the answer, unless you would prefer to do so.

Comment: Go ahead and write one up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @NathanOliver who pointed out that the `vector<T> rtn` object can be initialised with all the elements correctly allocated with a tiny change: Replace `std::vector<T> rtn (vecs.size());` with `std::vector<T> rtn (vecs);`.

Thus, the answer to the question is **a)** *use iterators to access the elements of the `std::vector` or `std::array` object* and **b)** *use the cleverness built in to the STL containers' constructors to ensure memory is correctly allocated*.

The working solution code is:

```c++
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<typename T>
std::vector<T>
process_vectors (const std::vector<T>& vecs) {
    // Create the return object with the same number of T objects in it as there are
    // in vecs, and with each T correctly allocated:
    std::vector<T> rtn (vecs);

    // Use iterators to work through vecs and rtn, as these are a common interface to
    // all the STL containers
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator vi = vecs.begin();
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator ri = rtn.begin();

    // For this example, let's just copy the input to the output, copying each T
    // element by element:
    while (vi != vecs.end()) {

        // For each mathematical vector in vecs, loop through its vector components:
        typename T::const_iterator vi_i = vi->begin();
        // And copy the result into the return's components:
        typename T::iterator ri_i = ri->begin();

        while (vi_i != vi->end()) {
            // The trivial example 'operation' of this function; performing a copy:
            *ri_i = *vi_i;
            // On to the next elements:
            ++vi_i;
            ++ri_i;
        }
        ++vi;
        ++ri;
    }

    return rtn;
}

int main() {
    // vector<array> version
    std::vector<std::array<float, 3>> the_vecs(3);
    the_vecs[0] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    the_vecs[1] = { 2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f };
    the_vecs[2] = { 3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f };
    std::vector<std::array<float, 3>> rtn_obj = process_vectors (the_vecs);
    cout << "vector<array> rtn_obj size is " << rtn_obj.size() << endl;
    cout << "Middle vector in rtn_obj2 is (" << rtn_obj[1][0] << "," << rtn_obj[1][1] << ","  << rtn_obj[1][2] << ")\n";

    // vector<vector> version
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> the_vecs2;
    the_vecs2.push_back ({ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f });
    the_vecs2.push_back ({ 2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f });
    the_vecs2.push_back ({ 3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f });
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> rtn_obj2 = process_vectors (the_vecs2);
    cout << "vector<vector> rtn_obj2 size is " << rtn_obj2.size() << endl;
    cout << "Middle vector in rtn_obj2 is (" << rtn_obj2[1][0] << "," << rtn_obj2[1][1] << ","  << rtn_obj2[1][2] << ")\n";

    return 0;
}
```

With output:

```
vector<array> rtn_obj size is 3
Middle vector in rtn_obj2 is (2,2,2)
vector<vector> rtn_obj2 size is 3
Middle vector in rtn_obj2 is (2,2,2)
```